# Find Dynamic Element Value .net

Tags: arrays, .net

I have a json(radiobuttons) as a dynamic object.

[image: Picture:]
I want to reach elements in this array.

```
(bool)marketingChoices.EMA ?  "Y" : "N";
```

But i will get this YES, NO , EMA etc info from outside.
So i want to write code dynamically,

```
(bool)marketingChoices.'String' ? "Y" : "N";
```

I can i make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, 
I can get the value, like this :

```
marketingChoices['String']
```